# Set debuild/dpkg to always ignore .git directories

Tags: git, ubuntu, debian, packaging, dpkg

To distribute my Ubuntu packages, I use `debuild -S` to create the source package and then upload it to launchpad, which creates the binary packages. This is very convenient. However, I noticed that my source packages are growing quickly in size, due to the fact that all of my packages contain a `.git` directory which is included in all the source packages.

What would be a way to set a global option so that debuild/dpkg always skips any `.git` directories when creating a source package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /somewhere/else
```

and then create the .deb from /somewhere/else which should not include a .git directory

Comment: Ugh. Was hoping for something global on the dpkg level.

Answer (score 8):

To ignore .git directory try: `debuild -S -i -I`

The `-i` option will ignore a number of files and directories that are created by VCS software, amongst others.  It will also ignore build artifacts that might still be around (`.so` files etc.)

Comment: Could you elaborate what the `-i` and `-l` options stand for?

Comment: The -i (--diff-ignore) and -I (tar-ignore) flags are flags that get passed to dpkg-source, and if no pattern is provided, will ignore some default set of patterns matching temporary and VCS files.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is in a Git repository, install `git-buildpackage` and use that for creating your Debian source package (`.dsc` and friends).

`git-buildpackage` sets the `-i` option to `dpkg-source` by default, which will ignore the `.git` directory when exporting to the source package.

It also brings a lot of additional functionality regarding creating Debian packages from a Git repository, which you might or might not need.